# Play iTunes play next

Tags: itunes

I have several songs in the Play Next queue.

I am not playing anything at the moment. How do I play the queue. Clicking play prompts me with a dialog asking if I want to overwrite the plainest queue or play the song selected in iTunes, but I just want the play next queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the up next queue and double-click on the title of the first song in the queue.

(In iTunes 12) the up next queue button looks like this:
[image: up next queue button]

It is in the top right corner of the playing now area of iTunes.

Comment: I do that and nothing happens - if I click on the ... I get various go toe and play next but it does not start playing

Comment: doubleclick works for me. On the song name, not on any of the buttons on the sides.

Comment: (changed the answer to say double-click)

Comment: That worked (sorry re down vote - the SO code thinks I voted after your edit - portal;y due to the 5 minutes leeway for editing)

Comment: eh, no worries, I should have been clearer the first time...